# C# Manage Monero keys

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

Looking at the resources for developers on Monero official website, I found **csharp-monero-rpc-client** library. It suggests interaction with **monero-wallet-rpc** process. But not all methods are implemented - for example, there is no method corresponding `make_integrated_address` endpoint. And key management, creation and sending of transactions lies entirely on **monero-wallet-rpc** side. Is there a library like NBitcoin where you can generate and manage all keys, generate and sign transactions on your side?

I'm also interested to know if it makes sense (or even necessary) to run Monero daemon. I am going to not only send transactions but also monitor the process of receiving confirmations.

Can I spend funds if the transaction has not yet been confirmed?

Answer (score 1):

> I found csharp-monero-rpc-client library. It suggests interaction with monero-wallet-rpc process. But not all methods are implemented...

There is no need for libraries like this. All they do is wrap the simple HTTP RPC API's exposed by the [daemon](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html) and [wallet](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html). If you know how to make a HTTP request and parse JSON, that's essentially all that's needed.

> I'm also interested to know if it makes sense (or even necessary) to run Monero daemon. I am going to not only send transactions but also monitor the process of receiving confirmations.

It is absolutely necessary to have access to a daemon, whether that be a local one or a remote one. That's because you cant check if you received funds or send funds without access to the network.

> Can I spend funds if the transaction has not yet been confirmed?

No.

Comment: And what about self-management of keys without an intermediary like monero-wallet-rpc?

Comment: How many confirmations must a transaction receive before the funds can be spent? It’s just that in the case of bitcoin, you can send 2 transactions at once, one of which uses funds from the outputs of the first one.

Comment: When we use an integrated address and funds are transferred to it with different payment IDs embedded in the address, is it possible to send all funds at once from this address to any other? Sorry, this is a bit off topic

Comment: "And what about self-management of keys" <- those wrapper libraries all just call the daemon/wallet RPC.

Comment: "How many confirmations..." <- 10 (~20 mins)

Comment: "is it possible to send all funds at once from this address to any other?" <- funds belong to a wallet, not an address, but yes you can spend outputs received at a specific address. See [transfer](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer).

Comment: That is, all projects that sending and accepting Monero use Wallet RPC calls?

Comment: Well, I mean that this is a common and normal practice.

Comment: "That is, all projects that sending and accepting Monero use Wallet RPC calls?" <- not all, but most. And all will use the daemon RPC as you can't transact without access to the network, which is via the daemon.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I understand the logic of the work correctly. I can simply create an integrated address by calling _make_integrated_address_, check receipts of funds by calling _get_payments_, and send funds from the same address to any address by calling _transfer_. There seems to be a limit to 1 integrated address in transaction outputs, so some exchanges block withdrawals to integrated addresses. This is true?

Comment: "This is true?" <- yes. This discussion is now completely off-topic wrt your question.